# Interpolation to fill missing data (x,y)

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data

I have a dataset of spectral measurements (x,y), for which the middle part (y) is missing (below is a subsample, missing is a series of spectrum data from 470nm to 570 nm):

```
300,07  9,742
307,07  11,245
318,07  12,543
342,07  13,599
360,07  14,194
370,07  14,574
375,07  14,734
392,07  15,246
405,07  15,654
420,07  16,238
467,07  17,257
524,07  
539,07  
593,07  20,65
608,07  21,21
621,07  21,745
625,07  21,898
629,07  21,941
650,07  22,788
671,07  23,475
687,07  24,087
692,07  24,29
```

I want to reconstruct the curve by estimating the missing y values by interpolation (either linear or spline) in an automated manner (I have more than 2000 files to process, so Excel is not an option!). I tried spline from plotutils (https://linux.die.net/man/1/spline) to do this, but the result doesn't make any sense:

```
300.07 9.742
317.888 12.5286
335.706 13.4152
353.525 13.9548
371.343 14.6128
389.161 15.2838
406.979 16.1991
424.797 10.6369
442.615 -22.6927
460.434 -13.5454
478.252 111.849
496.07 318.928
513.888 495.58
531.706 530.808
549.525 406.078
567.343 214.289
585.161 54.9759
602.979 17.0519
620.797 21.7555
638.615 22.1998
656.434 23.0396
674.252 23.5829
692.07 24.29
```

I searched for other options but haven't found anything specific for this. My programming experience is still very limited, so if anyone has any quick solution for this I would be very thankful!

---

Comment: Try omitting lines with no data: `awk 'NF>1' data | spline -n 22`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked wonders! I was looking at this from the wrong perspective.

Comment: It's a problem of low spline high demand.